# How to do SOAP web service testing in JMeter 2.13?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl, jmeter

How to do SOAP web service testing using JMeter 2.13 tool? 
JMeter 2.5.1 had an option to add WSDL path,Request data and etc.However current JMeter 2.13 version I could not see option to do SOAP web service testing JMeter 2.13.

Could you please help me to load WSDL,XML request and to verify response?

Comment: Did you try SOAP/XML-RPC Request? Can you be more specific what exactly didn't work?

Comment: When I use SOAP UI tool I will give WSDL file location and XML request.Once I run the query it will give XML response.JMeter 2.13 I dont know how to provide these details.I gave WSDL path in "URL" column and request in SOAP/XML data but I am not getting any response.Couls you please provide steps to do?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options:

1. [SOAP/XML-RPC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SOAP/XML-RPC_Request) Sampler (replica of the WebService(SOAP) Request)
2. [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) (in "Body Data" mode). You'll need to add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) in order to send `Content-Type` and `SOAPAction` headers.

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for more detailed explanation.